# CQL retrieve timeseries data by time range

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, partition, bucketing

I have sensors at different locations, each measuring multiple parameters. There will be around 2 millions of measurements per day per sensor. I need to query by location/time range, but the range specified will never be larger than couple of days. An example query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM meas WHERE latitude=46.1 AND longitude=15.1 AND measurementTime >= 2023-10-15T23:00:00Z AND measurementTime <= 2023-10-16T01:00:00Z;
```

To control partition size I can split partitions (I've read somewhere that this is called bucketing) based on time window - e.g. by day after epoch:

```
CREATE TABLE meas (
    latitude double,
    longitude double,
    dayOfMeasurement int,
    measurementTime timestamp,
    param1 double,
    param2 double, 
    param3 double, 
    etc...
    PRIMARY KEY ((latitude, longitude, dayOfMeasurement), measurementTime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (measurementTime DESC)
```

Now I have two options:

1. use IN in WHERE statement - like (assuming there were 19646 days from epoch to 16 Oct 2023):

```
SELECT * FROM meas WHERE latitude=46.1 AND longitude=15.1 AND dayOfMeasurement IN (19646,19645) AND measurementTime >= 2023-10-15T23:00:00Z AND measurementTime <= 2023-10-16T01:00:00Z;
```

2. or use multiple (two in the above example) separate queries and combine results on client side (I am using datastax Cassandra driver).

```
SELECT * FROM meas WHERE latitude=46.1 AND longitude=15.1 AND dayOfMeasurement=19645 AND measurementTime >= 2023-10-15T23:00:00Z AND measurementTime < 2023-10-16T00:00:00Z;
```

```
SELECT * FROM meas WHERE latitude=46.1 AND longitude=15.1 AND dayOfMeasurement=19646 AND measurementTime >= 2023-10-16T00:00:00Z AND measurementTime <= 2023-10-16T01:00:00Z;
```

Which of these two options is better? If option 2 is better - is there a standard way of combining the results of multiple queries in datastax java driver?
Or should I use some other data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There will be around 2 millions of measurements per day per sensor

I'd be curious as to how big the partitions are. TBH I would recommend breaking it down by hour in addition to day, as that seems like too many rows-per-partition. But if it already works fine, then it might be ok.

> use multiple (two in the above example) separate queries and combine results on client side

This is the approach that I'd recommend. The problem with the other approach (using `IN`) is that the order of the results returned will be inconsistent. It will be grouped by day and sensor and ordered by `measurementtime` within. But the order of the partitions will depend on the hash value of the token, which will not be consistent. So I'd say that some client-side work is necessary to ensure consistent behavior at the app level.

> Can you please elaborate a little further?

So generally speaking, it's a good idea to keep partition sizes under 1 or 2 MB. It's also a good practice to keep the number of rows per partition <= 100,000. When rowcounts or partition sizes exceed those values is when operations tend to slow down.

Now, those aren't hard, mathematical limits; just general guidelines. It's quite possible that a partition w/ 2 million really, *really* small rows could still work. I've even seen partitions sized at 10 MB or more be ok. It really comes down to payload sizes and access patterns. That's what I meant when I said above "if it already works, then it might be ok."

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little further? Splitting by day will probably be sufficient because 2 millions of measurements is going to be the worst case scenario (the sensor sampling rate changes with the environment). If it proves otherwise I will do the splitting by hour. But in this case I will have to make 24 queries to bring in one day of data. I am a Cassandra newbie but intuitively I do not like that many queries. What is a Cassandra 'best practice'  in finding the optimal partition size vs. number of queries ratio in such situation?

Comment: @jernejt edit made